# Input of Textboxes in a Dropdown Menu where I can edit these entries

Tags: php, html

is it possible to store the input of a Textbox in a Dropdown Menu and then edit/delete it in the Same Textbox after selecting it in the Dropdown Menu?

[image]

**My Old version where I store the input in a Textfile:**

```
<form action="namenerfassung2.php" method="get">

<p>First Name<br />
<input type="Text" name="namen" autocomplete="off" ></p>

<p>Surname<br />
<input type="Text" name="name" autocomplete="off" ></p>

<input type="Submit" name="" value="Speichern">
<select name="docsApp.options" size="10" multiple="multiple">
<option value="docsaktionen" title="" selected="selected" onclick="einrichtenCheck(this)">Hier Variable</option>
</select>
</br>
</br>
</form>

<?php
if ( $_GET['namen'] <> "" )
{
    // Open File
    $handle = fopen ( "nameliste.txt", "a");

    // write Name
    fwrite ( $handle, $_GET['namen'] );

    // Add a Space
    fwrite ( $handle, " " );

    // write Name
    fwrite ( $handle, $_GET['name']);
    $numberNewline = "\r\n";
    fwrite ( $handle, $numberNewline );

    // Close File
    fclose ( $handle );

    echo "Thanks - Your data was saved";

    // Exit File
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: I cant really understand your question, could you edit it to add more details

Comment: Can you unterstand it with the Picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use php for this, you need ajax calls.

simple solution is to alter that select client side (javascript / jQuery in this case) and then save it to your text file by php, load file contents on page load..

I added three clickable spans in my example: http://jsfiddle.net/b3da/wynhpdyp/

//EDIT: spans are now buttons, form is submiting only names displayed in select :)

//EDIT2: complete working example. Don't forget to save .php and namelist.txt in UTF-8 encoding. Don't use it on public server (or filter your inputs with PHP, before you do):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['names'])) {
    $names = $_POST['names'];
    file_put_contents('namelist.txt', $names);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('button').click(function(e) {
                var action = $(this).attr('data-action'),
                    optionVal = $('input[name="namen"]').val()+' '+$('input[name="name"]').val(),
                    $selectedOption = $('select[name="docsApp.options"] option:selected'),
                    $nameList = $('select[name="docsApp.options"]');

                if(action === 'add') {
                    $nameList.append($('<option>', {text:optionVal}));
                }
                if(action === 'edit') {
                    $selectedOption.text(optionVal);
                }
                if(action === 'remove') {
                    $selectedOption.remove();
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            $('select').click(function() {
                var selectedName = $('select[name="docsApp.options"] option:selected').text();

                $('input[name="namen"]').val(selectedName.split(' ')[0]);
                $('input[name="name"]').val(selectedName.split(' ')[1]);
            });

            $('form').submit(function(e) {
                var nameList = {},
                    names,
                    i = 0;

                $('select option').each(function(){
                    nameList[i] = $(this).text();
                    i++;
                });
                names = JSON.stringify(nameList);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '',
                    data: {'names':names},
                    success: function(){
                        $('.result').fadeIn(200).html('names saved').fadeOut(3000);
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <label>First Name
                <input type="Text" name="namen" autocomplete="off" >
            </label>
            <label>Surname
                <input type="Text" name="name" autocomplete="off" >
            </label>

            <button data-action='add'>add to list</button>
            <button data-action='edit'>overwrite selected name</button>
            <button data-action='remove'>remove from list</button>
            <br>
            <select name="docsApp.options" size="10" multiple="multiple">
                <?php
                    $names = json_decode(file_get_contents('namelist.txt'));
                    foreach ($names as $name) {
                        echo '<option>'.$name.'</option>';
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <br>
            <input type="Submit" name="" value="Speichern">
            <br>
        </form>
        <span class="result"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good One I hope it is fulfilling requirements,Better you would have used Buttons rather than <span>.

Comment: Looks great. I copied the Javascript Code and added it with <script> tags but they didnt do anything. Do I need to do something else?

Comment: You need to include jQuery before that script:     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @b3da OK, I included it at the top in head brackets. Now I get a blank page. <head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</head> The actual code is in <script language="JavaScript"> or does it need to be jQuery there aswell?